# fetch data from url with $.get() give me 404- url manager

Tags: yii2

i have this function in index.php view file.(see it below)
 as you see after click button it get data with get method

if my url be http://example.com/admin/site-developer/**index**

after click button in console i get error

```
GET http://example.com/admin/site-developer/site-developer/get-note?developer_id=7 404 (Not Found)
```

but with url without index at end it work correctly
http://example.com/admin/site-developer

if change $.(get) url to

```
$.get("get-note",{developer_id: Id},function(data) {}
```

after click http://example.com/admin/site-developer
give me

```
GET http://example.com/admin/get-note?developer_id=7 404 (Not Found)
```

error but if i add index to end of url it works corrctly

this is complete function code:

```
 $('#noteBtn').on('click',function(e) {
    $.get("site-developer/get-note",{developer_id: Id},function(data) {
       var data = JSON.parse(data);

    var elm = "";
    $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
     elm = elm+'<div id="id-'+i+'"><div>'+val.note+'</div><div>'+val.created_at+'</div></div>';
    });

    $("#developer_note").html(elm);

    })

;})
```

i think maybe its url manager problem??

here is my url manager config

```
   'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '/'=>'site/index',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            ],
        ],
```

action getnote

```
 public function actionGetNote($developer_id)
    {
        $model = DevelopersNote::findAll(['developer_id' => $developer_id]);
        echo Json::encode($model);
    }
```

Comment: update your question and show your site-developer controller action  get-note please

Comment: i added get-note action end of post @scaisEdge

Comment: you have configured the urlManager ?

Comment: i configed url manager  in web.php config i posted it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you url is not build properly

Assuming you javascript code is inside a php file

try use UrlHelper

```
<?php 
  use yii\helpers\Url;
?>

  $('#noteBtn').on('click',function(e) {
      <?php echo  'var myUrl = "' . Url::to(['site-developer/get-note'])  .  '";
        ' ; ?> 


       $.get(myUrl ,{developer_id: Id},function(data) {
         var data = JSON.parse(data);

      var elm = "";
      $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
       elm = elm+'<div id="id-'+i+'"><div>'+val.note+'</div><div>'+val.created_at+'</div></div>';
      });

      $("#developer_note").html(elm);

      })

  ;})
```

for check  your problem with the code above  try use this way

```
  $('#noteBtn').on('click',function(e) {
      var myUrl "http://example.com/admin/site-developer/get-note";
       $.get(myUrl ,{developer_id: Id},function(data) {
         var data = JSON.parse(data);

      var elm = "";
      $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
       elm = elm+'<div id="id-'+i+'"><div>'+val.note+'</div><div>'+val.created_at+'</div></div>';
      });

      $("#developer_note").html(elm);

      })

  ;})
```

Comment: i get syntax error with this in script

      <?= 'var myUrl = "' . Url::to(['site-developer/get-note'])  .  '";' ; ?>

Comment: again this line isnt ok

      <?php echo  'var myUrl = "' . Url::to(['site-developer/get-note'])  .  '";' ; ?>

Comment: your javascript is inside a php files?  .. have you adde the use for yii/helpers 
 then  if you can show me the resul for   <?php echo 'var myUrl = "' . Url::to(['site-developer/get-note']) . '";' ; ?>

Comment: can you please see this

Comment: i don't see  any error .. what is the error you get ?

Comment: console say Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and refrence it to that line of code

Comment: which console tell  you this  ... the browser  console or you ide  console ?

Comment: browser console

Comment: then using the code with echo if  you can see the html code generated  for the page and show me the real result for my code  .. i could understand where is the problem ..

Comment: var myUrl = "/site-developer/get-note";

it is echo resault